# How do I cut away joint compound?

Tags: caulking, cutting, joints

I used a square dowel to mostly fill a gap between a too-short vertical wood panel and the ceiling. The dowel had a slight warp, so when the glue dried, I added a layer of joint compound to bring it fully flush for painting, and also to fill the remaining ~1/8" gap to the ceiling. (There's no actual drywall, just wood and mud.) Of course, the mud started cracking at the ceiling just a few weeks later -- it's an old building so everything flexes -- and of course I should have used caulk to fill that last gap. I want to cut a new gap at the ceiling so I can remedy that, and my question is: how best to cut away the mud? The total I need to cut is about 10'. I'm thinking an oscillating tool will let me get right up to the ceiling. I know it'll be super dusty, and I'm prepared to sacrifice a blade (any suggestions there?), but it otherwise seems like the right tool. I welcome everyone's thoughts. Thanks!

Edit: The cracks are right where the drywall mud meets the ceiling, so I need to get some caulk in there instead to allow the ceiling to move independently. First step is to get rid of some of the mud to make room for the caulk.

Since first posting, I got a suggestion to cut the mud away with a razor knife, which sounds like more work than an oscillating tool but less dust -- a good thing since this is in a living space. Any thoughts on that would also be welcome.

Comment: I might not be understanding exactly how this is put together, but if you have a crack where the wall meets the ceiling, that's just caulk -- forget excavation. If there's a problematic crack below the corner, that might or might not be a candidate for caulk as well. Got a pic?